Get files that exists in A but not in B (content hash compare only)
Is there any way in WinMerge to see what files exist in path A but not in path B without comparing the folder structure?

On the face of it, that sounds like a silly question. After all, determining what files are in A and not in B is in fact comparing the folder structures. Are you trying to avoid comparing all the files in the two folders?
